# How can I read current console line input using C# using only one thread

Tags: c#, .net

So far `Console.ReadLine();` "returns the next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more lines are available" but it blocks the thread.

How would be a non-blocky way to read the text of the current line on Console ie. the text the user types in console using only one thread?

Comment: If you want another process to continue you might consider starting another thread. Although I wonder if it is that usefol cor a cmd program. You better can create a service then..

Comment: I am sorry, I wasn't clear, I'll edit my question. I wan't all of that happening in the same thread of course.

Comment: you can't with only one thread. something has to do your work

Comment: I can, and i am using a thread specific for Console stuff, so technichally Console.ReadLine works but blocks my loop.

Comment: I might really follow the answer for my _duplicate_ question, It seems the best direction. Thanks for all input's.